# How to restrict Client side people picker not to allow duplicate users?

Tags: javascript, people-picker, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am using Client Side People Picker as shown in [Use the client-side People Picker control in SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx).

Now the problem is, this people picker is allowing same user multiple times. I don't want the same user to allow multiple times.

So, is there any workaround how can I restrict same user multiple times in client side people picker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by checking `On Control Resolved Users Changed` event for the Client People picker. Please find more info [here](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-client-side-people.html) for Client People Picker Events.

You can try following script block to check if user is already entered in people picker.
Put this script at the end of `initializePeoplePicker` function definition as defined in your mentioned [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx)

```
this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
    console.log('inside OnUserResolvedClientScript');
    var users = selectedUsersInfo;
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length - 1; i++){
        if(users[users.length - 1].Key == users[i].Key){
            alert("User already exists");
            // Do something else...
        }

    }
};
```